# Receiving multicast UDP packets from a single network interface on macOS

Tags: c, macos, network-programming, udp, multicast

This is a macOS question. I am trying to setup a UDP socket that receives SSDP messages, i.e. UDP packets, sent to multicast addresses. I want to restrict receiving these packets from a single network interface.

I tried

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);  
char* itf = "en0";
int res = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, IP_RECVIF, itf, strlen(itf));
```

The setsockopt call fails with `errno 42` (Protocol not available).
I have also found `SO_BINDTODEVICE` that can be used for the same purpose, but it seems that this is not available on macOS.

Using bind with port and address also does not work. Then no packets sent to the multicast address are received on that socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OSX documentation on IP multicast](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/4/IP/)...

> A host must become a member of a multicast group before it can receive datagrams sent to the group.  To join a multicast group, use the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option...

To receive multicast traffic on a specific interface you need to tell the OS that you want to join that multicast group. Follow these steps (you were almost there)...

1. Create a datagram socket (done).
2. Bind to `INADDR_ANY` with the expected port.
3. Join the multicast group via `setsockopt()` with the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` option. Here you can pass the IP address of the specific network interface you wish to receive multicast traffic on in the `ip_mreq` struct.

Comment: Many thanks, that solved the problem. I am actually using GCDAsyncUdpSocket from Swift. The `joinMulticastGroup()`method accepts the interface as a second parameter. The implementation than uses `setsockopt()` with `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`. Not sure why someone down voted your answer.